# What is the compatible version of Selenium RC with Selenium IDE 2.5.0?

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have installed the selenium ide 2.5.0 add-on for firefox and after exporting the test case as Java/JUnit 4/ Web Driver. When I try to execute it with JUnit testing I always get exceptions when some class from selenium is not found. I have used selenium-api-4.2.0.jar and selenium-server-stendalone-2.42.2.jar. Than I have also tried switching from selenium-api-4.2.0.jar to selenium-api-2.42.2.jar but there always a class missing. 
Which is the correct selenium-api and selenium-server-stendalone Jar to use for the 2.5.0 IDE?
Thnx in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [graphic in the documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) shows you how all the jars relate to each other. The selenium-server-standalone by itself contains all of those and all the dependencies.

Selenium IDE does not export code that uses the Selenium-RC API, it only uses Selenium WebDriver API.

Generally, unless you are doing something very particular, you want to use the latest stable release of everything.

If you still have problems, have a read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post your code, post your error messages.